# how to display a listview dropping down from the button on onclick event?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to display a list of messages on click of a button on the same page by shifting the other buttons to one side. The image given specifies the requirement of my app. How do i display different list of messages for each button in the following way?

How do i achieve this? Please Help!

[image]

Comment: just keep a map of buttons to lists and use `setVisible()` for ListView

Comment: Use Expandable ListView instead.. http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

You should use this library!
I think it can help you !

Comment: Are you asking or answering?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a custom "button" which xml holds a button and a listview, and his class a button name, an arraylist of values, and a listadapter for poulate the listview. You could personalize the onitemclick method of that listview so you can personalize every button.